# Upload file returning “Missing a temporary folder”

Tags: php, linux

I have my site hosted on GoDaddy and on that site I have a part for uploads, it worked fine until days ago, now it started to return error 6 - Missing a temporary folder for any file I try to upload, I tried several ways to solve it, changing the php.ini and still nothing.

In my PHP file if I use the command `file_exists(sys_get_temp_dir());` returns me true, so the folder is there.

If I use the `is_writable(sys_get_temp_dir());` command returns me false, maybe there is the problem, but the folder `/tmp` on my server has permission `drwxrwxrwt.`

If anyone can help me with this problem, since I followed several tutorials and nothing about the solution.

Comment: have you tried setting the temp folder for uploads somewhere other than `/tmp`? I can image the permissions are restricted there on shared hosting. Try a folder within your project for example

Comment: Then there is another problem, when I configure `upload_tmp_dir` to another folder, it does not change, even after changing, when I run `phpinfo()` the `upload_tmp_dir` directive has a value `no value`. My hosting is a VPS and not a shared hosting. 
To edit php.ini I use the MultiPHP INI Editor area in the CPanel of my hosting.

Comment: If the dir is empty then this sounds like your initial problem since PHP does not know where to put the file. You should figure out why the value is not changed with your hoster.

Comment: I will check with GoDaddy if they can solve this problem and return with some answer to continue or finalize this post.

Comment: I checked with GoDaddy and they really can't help anything, because VPS their support is very limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem has been solved and it is more strange than I imagined, I will leave the answer here to help you if someone has the same problem.

It was necessary to execute the command `chmod 777 / tmp`, but this command could not be executed since it gave an error that the folder was read-only (Ready-Only file system). To resolve this, it was necessary to mount and remount it, but I couldn't do it either, as it wouldn't let me remount the `/tmp` folder

For another reason I had to restart the server and magically the server let me change the permissions to 777 (from `drwxrwxrwt.` to `drwxrwxrwx.`). With that problem solved.

I thank everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Some providers do NOT grant access to the initialization file for PHP, but rather customers must use a local php.ini file with only the entries needed and allowed to set in a customer account.

In the server's Site Administration menu -> Server -> PHP Info what does the output show for upload_tmp_dir?

More than likely on a shared host, one cannot access edit the main php.ini, but one can set some things via their own local (in their account) php.ini file with the right 'snippets'.

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't find the part where you say `Site Administration menu -> Server -> PHP Info`, however if I run `phpinfo()` on my site the return for `upload_tmp_dir` is `no value`.

My server is not shared, it is a VPS, and I edit my php.ini file through the `MultiPHP INI Editor` on my CPanel, this file has the following directives for upload_tmp_dir: `upload_tmp_dir =  /home/sitebiblical/public_html/tmp` and this folder exists.